# TYPO3 Best practice assigning cObject data to view since getContentObject() is depricated

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

I was wondering how this is solved in modern extensions, but could not figure it out. Most of them just magical using e.g. `{data.uid}` inside their views without any `$view->assign('data',...)`

In my old actions I had used something like this:

```
public function myAction() {
  $data = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;
  $this->view->assign('data', $data);
}
```

Since `getContentObject()` is marked as deprecated in v8, it should be replaced with `getContentObjectRenderer()`, but the Configuration-Manager has not such a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK after playing around a while and searching through a lot of classes, it seems that the original solution is still valid, the deprecated message applied to another class which has no meaning in this case:

```
$cObjectData = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;
$view->assign('data', $cObjectData);
```

The Extension File Scanner was miss leading me with its warning, there is no deprecated message inside the logs using this solution,... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 v12 and v13 you can use the following code within a controller:

```
$cObjectData = $this->request->getAttribute('currentContentObject')
```