# $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data returns empty array typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am using typo3 9.5 . I need to fetch all the data of the current content element in my extension's controller.

```
public function listAction()
    {
        /* Some Codes */
        $this->contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data);
        $this->view->assign('data', $this->contentObj->data);
    }
```

It returns empty. But in another plugin in the same extension returns the value array . How can I solve the issue ?

Comment: As mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239832/typo3-best-practice-assigning-cobject-data-to-view-since-getcontentobject-is-d  
and according to my own tests the problem is not caused by `$this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data` or it's underlaying logic. This snippet still provides access to the cobject and works as expected.  
Please provide some context and some code and point out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is the Plugin inserted as content element in the page? If the plugin is only renderes only by typoscript to data array is empty.

Comment: Plugin inserted as content element

Answer (score 0):

Note that `getContentObject()` has been deprecated and does not work in TYPO 3.9 ([reference](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.0/Deprecation-68748-DeprecateAbstractContentObjectgetContentObject.html)).

Comment: The deprecation is related to a method of `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\AbstractContentObject` rather than the `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager` … apparently one of the false positives mentioned in the extension scanner