# Accessing the Layout Field in typo3 my Extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

How can i access the Layout Property of my Plugin in the controller?
On Page Side i do the following: {data.layout}.

But i cant find a variable for the plugin Layout. I need sometthing like:
{myPlugin.layout}

Thanks for the help

[image: Plugin Screenshot]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54288790/6812729

Comment: @MathiasBrodala Thanks!!!! i was looking for it the last few hours! ❤️